# Magento invoice link to pdf in transactional email

Tags: invoice, transactional

I remember myself asking this question before and closing it again. Maybe it could not be done.....

We are investingating this option because it helps us in not sending a 1-2MB attachment to our customers.

But only after today when investigating  mywebstore.com/sales/guest/form I found something that could be helpful to access an order, without logging in ...

```
{{store url=""}}/sales/guest/print/order_id/{{var order.id}}/
```

Investigating now.

If any other mehtods exist I am interested.

Comment: Is the whole email size problem not related to the font being used to create the PDF files?

Comment: Yes - that is the main driver yes. Plus also that magento does not allow to attach the pdf invoice by default